# Создание текста на PNG картинке

Tags: php

Есть задача создать текст на прозрачном месте png картинки (т.к. когда у меня та часть была залита белом текст выводился нормально), а сейчас в том месте куда нужен текст прозрачно сделал и текст выглядет как-то нечётко и не ровно, как будто кто-то кисточкой нарисовал) Шрифт arial.ttf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мануал рулит) Прописал

```
imagesavealpha($im, 1);
```

И всё нормализовалось)